# Multiple IPFS private network on same machine

Tags: javascript, database, hyperledger-fabric, ipfs

Is there a way to have multiple IPFS private network on same machine.
Explanation in detail:
Can node 0 have multiple ipfs private networks running in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not neatly possible. You should be able to run several nodes on one host, but when requesting a file, you still have to know in which of the nodes to look.